# How to open multiple selected files in one instance of application

Tags: c#, winforms

First of all sorry for my bad English.

I have created an image viewer application (Windows form application). After making it default program for all image types, when I double click on single image file in Windows explorer, it is working nicely.

But when I want to open multiple selected images from Windows explorer, then every image opens in a new instance of my viewer.

So what I do now?

Comment: So what do you want?

Comment: I want all the selected images open in only one instance

Comment: Is your app a multi document interface (MDI) app? Will it be able to open multiple images as seperate windows (forms)

Comment: I've chosen the marked duplicate because it provides one of the simpler solutions (use the VB.NET support library, which has this functionality built-in). See also (if you like) [What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19147), which has more extensive discussion and answers on the question, though you will need to handle argument passing between processes yourself with some of the answers there.